# How to get the nested child data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, t-sql, linq-to-sql

I have two tables as below:

Table1 :

```
SectionID SectionName 
 1        ParentSection1
 2        ChildSection1
 3        ChildSection2
 4        ChildChildSection1
```

Table2:

```
DependentID ParentID ChildID
1           1        2
2           1        3
3           2        4
```

OutPut :

```
ParentId ParentSectionName    ChildSectionName
1        ParentSection1       ChildSection1
1        ParentSection1       ChildSection2
1        ParentSection1       ChildChildSection1
```

What motto is to get the sub hierarchy which comes to the parent sections as child sections.

What I have done till now :

```
Select 
    t.Section as ParentID,t.SectionName as ParentSection, 
    c.SectionName as ChildSection 
from 
    Table1 t 
join 
    Table2 d on t.SectionID = d.ParentID 
right join
    c.Table1 on c.SectionID = d.ChildID 
where 
    t.SectionID = 1
```

SQL or Linq both will be helpful. Please help me in this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As a SQL solution you can use [recursive Common Table Expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(SectionID INT, SectionName VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO Table1(SectionID, SectionName )
VALUES
( 1,        'ParentSection1'),
 (2 ,       'ChildSection1'),
 (3  ,      'ChildSection2'),
 (4   ,     'ChildChildSection1');

CREATE TABLE Table2(DependentID INT, ParentID INT,    ChildID INT);

INSERT INTO Table2(DependentID, ParentID, ChildID)
VALUES
(1,           1        ,2),
(2,           1        ,3),
(3,           2        ,4)

;with cte (ParentId2, ChildID2, TopLevelParentID) as 
(
    select  ParentID, ChildID, ParentID as TopLevelParentID
    from    Table2 as t
    -- this is anchor condition, selects top level parents, those who aren't anyone's child
    where   ParentID not in (select distinct ChildID from Table2)
    union all
    select  ParentID, ChildID, cte.TopLevelParentID
    from    Table2 as t
    inner join cte 
    on      cte.ChildID2 = t.ParentId
)

select  TopLevelParentID as ParentId
        , tParent.SectionName as ParentSectionName
        , tChild.SectionName as ChildSectionName
from    cte
inner join Table1 as tParent
on      tParent.SectionID = cte.TopLevelParentID
inner join Table1 as tChild
on      tChild.SectionID = cte.ChildID2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get data from a tree with an arbitrary number of levels, you should use a recursive SQL statement. It should be fairly easy to Google an example of this. :)

Comment: To add some details: You can make a recursive SQL statement using a temp table with a union.

Comment: If I want it to be a linq statement then ? :(

Comment: Dunno. Maybe try the same approach as in SQL? Otherwise, you can always just extract the relevant data and organize it in your code.

Comment: Maybe find a SQL to Linq tool?

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you are looking for tree in sql and you need to get the path of any leaf to the root or any other task related to a tree. 
Instead of this model, I suggest **`Adjacency List Model`** or **`Nested Set Model`** to handle tree form data in SQL. 
Both have strengths and weaknesses. [Here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) you can find detail information about both of them and their real SQL usages. 
**If** you choose any of them, you can delete your second table and handle the situation with only one table and no need for complex SQL queries (indeed with these two model, there will be complex queries too, but not redundant like the ones you need to have in the current model).
 Lets assume that you chose the Nested Set Model(you may read Wiki here: [nested set model in wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)), your table definition will be:

```
SectionID      SectionName           lft    rgt
---------      -----------           ---    ---
 1             ParentSection1
 2             ChildSection1
 3             ChildSection2
 4             ChildChildSection1
```

You need to set appropriate values for right and left columns (There is a rule to find them out for all the leaves, do not enter them randomly - You need to read about the Nested set theory in the link given above), and when you did so, you can find any path between two leaves by already written SQL queries or you can find all the descendants for any root or ancestors of any leaf you want.